# Install of Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 13.10, windows-7

I am running an HP Pavilion dv7 laptop with 2 hard drives (sda, sdb). I want to install Ubuntu 13.10 64bit on sdb, at present I have Windows 7 64bit booting on sda. My question is: If I install 13.10 64bit on sdb, will the boot partition that boots W7 see 13.10 on sdb and allow 13.10 64bit to load BURG? If not, can it be made to do so? A friend told me that what I'm trying to do will not work. Of course he isn't sure why it won't work or how to fix it. If I have not given enough information, or if what I have given isn't clear, please ask me, and I will try to provide a better explanation. Thanks for all of your help in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need 1 boot manager like the one that comes with Windows, or Burg or Grub or Lilo, etc.

The best course of action is to install Ubuntu on sdb, let Ubuntu install Grub, and you'll get a menu that will give you the option to choose whether to boot Windows or Ubuntu.

If you really want Burg you can install it instead of Grub.

Comment: Thanks.  When installing the 13.10 64bit iso to sdb, do I tell it to use the MOUNT point on SDA? or use the one on SDB?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you want to be in Ubuntu and access the files on the Windows partition, then you can choose to mount the `/dev/sda` on a directory you want. This can be made on anytime, doesn't necessary have to be made in the installation process